# Distribute GStreamer streams

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

Currently I have a h264 stream from a webcam and piping it to an udpsink. On the other side I have an udpsrc and showing the stream via a xvimagesink element. Works pretty well.

But what I want is: streaming the h264 stream to a central server, where other clients can connect to and receive the stream. (because bandwidth of streaming device is pretty small)

Requirements:

- Users should be able to connect using vlc or other simple clients
- as low as possible latency (beside of network latency)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by sending the stream out through gstreamer's RTSP server. VLC is fully capable of reading an RTSP stream(I have tested with H264 myself doing this and it works great!).

[Here are some Examples](https://github.com/sebp/gst-rtsp-server/tree/master/examples) that somebody put up on GitHub.

One gotcha that I have ran into is that if the server is not grabbing the sources themselves, there will have to be a "spin up" time for the server(like listening on a `udpsrc`).

The RTSP servers pipelines do not start unless there is somebody listening and automatically stops when all clients leave the pool. So, you may have to send a signal, or have a local rtspsrc element that requests the stream as soon as it is sent to the server to be distributed.